# Setting a HKLM key from a non-privileged application

Tags: c#, registry

I am trying to set a HKLM registry key from a non-elevated application. To do this, I use a `ProcessInfo` to call `reg.exe` to set the key. But, whatever I try, no key is added or set.

This is the code:

```
Process p;
ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo;

ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("reg.exe", "add HKLM\\Software\\MyVendor\\MyApplication /v somevalue /t REG_SZ /d content");
ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
ProcessInfo.Verb = "runas";
p = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
p.WaitForExit(1000);
p.Close();
```

I have done something similar in the past with `route.exe`, which worked fine.

Comment: Other way around is to create `reg`-file and run it with `regedit.exe`. Or `reg.exe` /unsure

Comment: Look in HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node.  If you see it there then you started the 32-bit version of reg.exe.